# Azure DevOps complete PR with oAuth token

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am having an issue with a simple extension to complete pull request from a release pipeline. From my understanding, the release pipeline will use the built in service account. I have basically given this user full access in a test project. I can get the pull request information and check the status. When it attempt to update the status the API returns "The user '' is not authorized to access this resource." I have tested this with a PAT and it works so I'm pretty sure it is a permission issue.

What am I missing?

[image: Image of permissions to built in user]